# AJAX/PHP/MySQL/HTML Search MySQL based off of generated variable and display cell in table

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am building a custom part builder and I am trying to make it search the MySQl Database by the Part Number that is generated and then output the price into cell in a table. I can't figure out how to make it search by the Part Number that is generated and output the price. The Part Number is generated by Javascript but an example part number would be 133-FTHxFTH-075-N1-00. Here is my Ajax script

`var request = $.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost/filenamehere.php",
     type: "post",
     data: "partnumber"
     });
     request.done(function (response) {
     document.getElementById("price1").innerHTML = response;
     });`

Here is my PHP Code

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 'LDS_Price_$' FROM list where 
Part_Number=**This is wher the generated part number would go** ");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>LDS Price $</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['LDS_Price_$'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>`
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the code?

Comment: Your filenamehere.php needs to connect to the database, run the query and return the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your php file si returning just the price in plain text...

```
myPartNumber = '133-FTHxFTH-075-N1-00';

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost/filenamehere.php",
    data: { partnumber: myPartNumber },
    dataType: 'html',
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#price').html(data);
    }
});
```

I hope it helps